# R how to mutate a new column that has the same vector size

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to create a new column that converts FIPS code to the state abbreviation using library(usmap), the problem is that the new column after using mutate does not match the matrix size. The new column only has 51 rows after using fips_info, but not 23570 rows of the original matrix.

Appreciate any help, thanks!

```
#defined function to get state abb
fips_function <- function(fips_code){
  return (fips_info(fips_code)$abbr)
}

atus_19_selected <- act_19 %>%
  mutate(state_abb = fips_function(GESTFIPS))

Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `state_abb`.
x Input `state_abb` can't be recycled to size 23570.
ℹ Input `state_abb` is `fips_function(GESTFIPS)`.
ℹ Input `state_abb` must be size 23570 or 1, not 51.


atus_19_selected
# A tibble: 23,570 x 8
   GESTFIPS GTCO  TUCASEID t150701 t150799 t150801 t150899 t159999
      <dbl> <chr>    <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
 1       40 000    2.02e13      60       0       0       0       0
 2       51 153    2.02e13      40       0       0       0     260
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue would be that some of the values are duplicates, so, it would return the error.  An option is `rowwise`

```
library(usmap)
library(dplyr)
act_19 %>%
     rowwise %>%
     mutate(state_abb = fips_function(GESTFIPS)) %>%
     ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#  GESTFIPS state_abb
#     <dbl> <chr>    
#1       40 OK       
#2       51 VA       
#3       40 OK
```

---

Or another option is to run this on the `distinct` values of 'GESTFIPS' and then do a join

```
act_19 %>%
    distinct(GESTFIPS) %>%
    mutate(state_abb = fips_function(GESTFIPS)) %>%
    right_join(act_19)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#  GESTFIPS state_abb
#     <dbl> <chr>    
#1       40 OK       
#2       40 OK       
#3       51 VA
```

---

The error can be reproduced with the duplicate values

```
act_19 %>%
   mutate(state_abb = fips_function(GESTFIPS))
```

> Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `state_abb`.
> ✖ Input `state_abb` can't be recycled to size 3.
> ℹ Input `state_abb` is `fips_function(GESTFIPS)`.
> ℹ Input `state_abb` must be size 3 or 1, not 2.
> Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

This issue arises directly from subsetting

```
usmap:::get_fips_info
function (fips) 
{
    if (all(nchar(fips) == 2)) {
        df <- utils::read.csv(system.file("extdata", "state_fips.csv", 
            package = "usmap"), colClasses = rep("character", 
            3), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
        result <- df[df$fips %in% fips, ]  # -> would subset only for unique fips
        
...
```

#### data

```
act_19 <- tibble(GESTFIPS = c(40, 51, 40))
```

Answer (score 1):

When `fips_info` cannot match a FIPS code for some reason, it does not return anything for that entry, so you cannot guarantee a 1-to-1 input/output relationship.

Using a known-defect highlights this:

```r
act_19 <- structure(list(GESTFIPS = c(40L, 99L), GTCO = c(0L, 153L), TUCASEID = c(2.02e+13, 2.02e+13), t150701 = c(60L, 40L), t150799 = c(0L, 0L), t150801 = c(0L, 0L), t150899 = c(0L, 0L), t159999 = c(0L, 260L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2"))

usmap::fips_info(act_19$GESTFIPS)
# Error in fips_info.numeric(act_19$GESTFIPS) : 
#   Invalid FIPS code(s), must be either 2 digit (states) or 5 digit (counties), but not both.

usmap::fips_info(as.character(act_19$GESTFIPS))
# Warning in get_fips_info(fips_) :
#   FIPS code(s) 99 not found, excluded from result.
#   abbr fips     full
# 1   OK   40 Oklahoma
```

I suggest an alternative method:

```r
abbrs <- usmap::fips_info(as.character(unique(act_19$GESTFIPS)))
# Warning in get_fips_info(fips_) :
#   FIPS code(s) 99 not found, excluded from result.
abbrs
#   abbr fips     full
# 1   OK   40 Oklahoma

abbrs %>%
  transmute(state_abb = abbr, GESTFIPS = as.integer(fips)) %>%
  right_join(act_19, by = "GESTFIPS")
  state_abb GESTFIPS GTCO TUCASEID t150701 t150799 t150801 t150899 t159999
1        OK       40    0 2.02e+13      60       0       0       0       0
2      <NA>       99  153 2.02e+13      40       0       0       0     260
```

You may still have entries with incorrect `state_abb`, but at least you'll retain all of your previous data and won't get that error.

Comment: *It will be*. For instance, try `act_19$state_abb <- usmap::fips_info(as.character(act_19$GESTFIPS))$abbr` with my sample data. It will warn, but incorrectly assign `"OK"` to both rows. It doesn't error, because recycling works here. Any code that works when the recycling works is bound to have incorrect data in it. The join attempt (that you also had) will preempt this problem. So while my data does not show the recycling error, it shows the same *problem*.

Comment: That first error message may not be included in the original complaint, sure. I retained it to demonstrate why I was forcing `as.character` and `as.integer`.